# javascript Logical operator In string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this `"(ReadAccountAccess || ReadContractAccess) && CreateAccountAccess"`

And I have this object:

```
{
  PermissionID: 1,
  AccountID: 1,
  ReadAccountAccess: true,
  ReadContractAccess: true,
  CreateAccountAccess: true,
}
```

How can I check this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is NOT recommended, but you could use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement and evaluate the expression with that object as the scope.

```js
function check(obj, condition) {
  with(obj) {
    return eval(condition)
  }
}

const input={PermissionID:1,AccountID:1,ReadAccountAccess:true,ReadContractAccess:true,CreateAccountAccess:true};

console.log( 
  check(input, "(ReadAccountAccess || ReadContractAccess) && CreateAccountAccess"),
  check(input, "ReadAccountAccess === false"),
  check(input, "AccountID === 1") 
)
```

Instead of saving the condition in a string, you could use a function which takes an object as an input and returns the condition expression. This is a much better of deferring the check.

```js
const input={PermissionID:1,AccountID:1,ReadAccountAccess:true,ReadContractAccess:true,CreateAccountAccess:true};

const c1 = o => (o.ReadAccountAccess || o.ReadContractAccess) && o.CreateAccountAccess,
      c2 = o => o.ReadAccountAccess === false,
      c3 = o => o.AccountID === 1

console.log(
  c1(input),
  c2(input),
  c3(input)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` javascript function.

```js
const obj = {
  PermissionID: 1,
  AccountID: 1,
  ReadAccountAccess: true,
  ReadContractAccess: true,
  CreateAccountAccess: true,
};

const { PermissionID, AccountID, ReadAccountAccess, ReadContractAccess, CreateAccountAccess } = obj;

const opr = "(ReadAccountAccess || ReadContractAccess) && CreateAccountAccess";
console.log(eval(opr));
```